# I got badly scammed and hacked. Please help!

Tags: malware, windows, wifi, router

I got scammed and hacked. The scammers said they were from Microsoft and my computer had virus and they were going to install some antivirus software on my computer and clean the virus for me. So I let them remotely connected to my computer for more than an hour! God knows what they’ve been doing in that time!

Afterwards I realized that it’s a scam. So I took the computer that they connected with to the computer repairs and get it totally reset.

I thought that would solve the problem. But no!

The next morning I used another computer in my house to change my Microsoft account password. I thought I would be safe because this computer was not the one the directly connected with. So I changed my Microsoft account password.

2 hours after I changed the Microsoft account password, I logged into my microsoft account again. I checked “Recent Activities” page. Guess what? Right after I changed to a new password, someone successfully logged into my Microsoft account! And their ip is somewhere in Hong Kong while I’m in New Zealand.

I didn’t understand how they could know my new password? This computer they didn’t directly connect yesterday.

Then I thought, they must have hacked into my wifi network, so they can access all the devices in my house.

I logged into my router, and checked the system log, I can see lots and lots of “alert”, “intrusion” written in the log. I think that means someone really hacked into my router. Don’t know if that is right?

So after they hacked into my router, can they install spyware onto all the devices in my house? Or they just can see all the data that’s in and out without even install spyware? How were they able to get my new password?

I’m not sure what to do now. Should I check and clean malware on all the devices first, or should I fix the hacked router problem first?
 me. I called twice about it. One person said they were not allowed to do that. The second person said that she can’t find the option to change it. So she think my router is a faulty one and she’s sending me a new router in a few days.

So my question is, will my problem be solved when I change to a new router?

I'm using Windows 10 on all my pc.

I got myself into deep trouble this time. Please help me to get out of the hack.

Comment: I would reset all my connected devices and add second factor (phone, sms ...) to my all online accounts.

Answer (score 7):

A quick and effective solution would be to disconnect all your devices from the internet and perform a factory reset on your router.

With the router reset, I would consider backing up important files and restoring to a fresh installation of your Windows 10.  Be sure to change passwords and not re-use passwords that may have been compromised already.

This solution won't require you to spend a lot of time trying to track down exactly what happened to your network and devices.

Comment: Backup important *data* files, like pictures and documents you need.  Reinstall any *applications* from trusted media.  You don't want to bring any compromised software over to your new windows 10 install

Comment: My further question is, there are 9 devices in my house: 2 desktops, 2 laptops, 1 iphone, 1 ipad, 1 android phone, 2 android tablets. Do I need to reset all of those devices? Would there be a problem if I leave one or two of the devices not reset? Would the hacker get into my network again through the one device that's not reset?

Is it not necessary to reset the iphone and ipad? One of the android tablet has got seem like Adware on it, ads popping up all the time. How can I reset this tablet?

Comment: @kekehaung11 It depends on how much effort the attacker has put into compromising your network. In most cases I wouldn't worry too much about your iOS devices if their OS's are kept up to date. If your Android tablet is acting up you can consider doing a factory reset (Google how to).  If you think another computer is infected your safest bet is loading up a clean OS.

Answer (score 1):

Excellent point about never reusing those passwords. If the 'hackers' get in again in the future you will need to repeat the whole reset process again. Also I would suggest changing passwords on devices you maybe have used the same or similar password with.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice! Actually my ISP is sending me a brand new router, so that would solve the reset router problem.